# How to call class by its name dynamically in Kotlin

Tags: android, class, kotlin, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Assume I have a fragment called "LoginFragment". I want to use this fragment in add transaction below:

```
fTransaction.add(R.id.login_fragment, LoginFragment())
```

But I need call it by name dynamically like this:

```
val name = "LoginFragment"
fTransaction.add(R.id.login_fragment, name())
```

How should I do this?
Thank you

Comment: Kotlin is statically-typed language, you can't do dynamic typing here, the Types are resolved at compile-time.

Comment: You could however make a checking function `operator fun String.invoke(): Fragment { if(this == "LoginFragment") return LoginFragment() else throw IllegalArgumentException("Message") }` or you could chain them using a `when` instead of `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to instantiate a `Fragment` by it's name you can use [`FragmentFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentFactory) to instantiate the `Fragment`:

```
try {
    val fragmentName = "LoginFragment"
    val fragmentFullName = "your.package.name.$fragmentName"
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(classLoader, fragmentFullName)
    supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.login_fragment, fragment)
            .commitNow()
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```